# Android Xamarin I want to open web-view with safari browser without installing safari to my phone

Tags: android, webview, xamarin, safari, android-developer-api

**Android Xamarin** : I want to open web-view with safari browser without installing safari to my phone (like we do in Web Application with dll files, without installing software we can use it )

Comment: There is no Safari on Android. Do you mean Chrome?

Comment: no i want to open my webview with safari browser while safari can be install in android phone

Comment: Or If we can set safari as default browser with code so that anything we open with the url link automatically safari will open that perticular link or webview

Comment: Again, there is no Apple Safari browser available on the Android platform.